# generate 4 digit pin using str_shuffle in php but sometime get 3 digit number

Tags: php

I'm trying to generate a 4 digit pin using `str_shuffle` function and its working fine the only problem is that sometimes I get a 3 digit pin also. How to resolve this??

```
substr(str_shuffle("0123456789"), 0, 4);
```

Comment: What do you do with this string you get from that? Do you save it as a number (integer)? The problem is not in the code you show here. You need to show us when you save it or output it.

Comment: You might be treating the pin number as an integer somewhere. If it starts with a zero, that zero might be dropped. So, 0123 would become 123.

Comment: @M.Hemant Rand generated integers and will definitely make 3 or less numbered pins.

Comment: try to use echo rand(1000, 9999);die; or remove 0 from your str_shuffle()

Comment: @M.Hemant that will remove 1000 possible pin numbers. And OPs code creates unique digits in the pin, there can't be two `1` in his code but yours could be `1111`. I'm not saying it's wrong, it's just not what OP has.

Comment: even i am also thinking the same @ KIKO Software

Answer (score 0):

You can use mt_rand(1000,9999)
Instead of str_shuffle

Answer (score 0):

You can get like this :-

```
function gen_code($code_len, $char = FALSE) {
  $chars = '0123456789';
  if ($char) {
   $chars = 'AB0CD1EF2GH3IJ4KL5MN6OP7QR8ST9UVWXYZ';
  }
  $code = '';
  $i = 0;
  while ($i < $code_len) {
   $code .= substr($chars, mt_rand(0, strlen($chars) - 1), 1);
   $i++;
  }
  return $code;
 }
```